# Is there a card that has opponents discard cards whenever they lose life?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was wondering whether I could create an infinite loop using [Fell Specter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFell%20Specter%5d) and a card with an ability similar to or exactly like this one:

> Whenever an opponent loses life, that player discards a card.

Does anyone know of such a card? Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4):

No, as [this search](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3Awhenever+o%3A%22loses+life%22&order=name&as=text&unique=cards) reveals.

Noteable:

- [Mindcrank](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMindcrank%5d): "Whenever an opponent loses life, that player puts that many cards from the top of their library into their graveyard." Extremely close to what you requested, but it doesn't trigger [Fell Specter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFell%20Specter%5d)'s ability.
- [Exquisite Blood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bExquisite%20Blood%5d): "Whenever an opponent loses life, you gain that much life." It forms a similar combo with [Sanguine Bond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSanguine%20Bond%5d) and [Epicure of Blood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEpicure%20of%20Blood%5d) instead of [Fell Specter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFell%20Specter%5d).

Answer (score 3):

### There aren't any, and there won't be any.

Players get priority during the draw step after the draw.  This means that instant speed discard has the ability to rob a player of the ability to play their sorcery speed cards before they ever get the opportunity to play them.

As a consequence, Wizards really hates printing instant speed discard, and hates *repeatable* instant speed discard even more so.  There's enough ways to deal damage at instant speed to make a card like the one you want to qualify as repeatable instant speed discard, so they aren't going to print it in the foreseeable future.

Furthermore, the [Underworld Dreams](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnderworld%20Dreams%5d) effect has been printed several times, and is powerful enough that people have built competitive decks around it even without adding a loop to the deck.

Discard and land destruction are two of the most closely monitored deck strategies, because Wizards thinks that being unable to play your spells is the least fun position to be in, and players who aren't having fun tend to stop buying cards.

Comment: You are probably correct, WoTC has done crazier things in the past. If they wanted to the could create a card that does what OP wants, but without violating what you have outline in your answer. (ie. "If it is your turn and your opponent loses life, they discard a card)

Comment: More likely, in my opinion, is "at the beginning of each end step, every opponent who lost life this turn discards a card"

Comment: That is more possible (and they kinda shorta have something similar in standard right now [Raiders' Wake](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=435270)), but that doesn't create the loop that OP is looking for. I also don't think that the loop is that bad, or even that different from normal discard since it will end pretty quick once the Opp runs out of cards in hand.

Comment: +1 and it goes further than that. This kind of effect is very dangerous because it can easily lead to forced discards of multiple cards. For example connecting with two 1/1s would now discard two cards - that's an obscene power level. If this kind of effect ever sees print, it'll likely be in some extremely hard-to-reach place, e.g. costing 15 mana or a planeswalker ultimate.

Comment: There was a similar issue with Yu-Gi-Oh with a card that makes players discard cards, and does a tiny amount of damage. If you can wipe the board, and then make them discard all their cards and then make them discard one card per turn, then they're locked down, and can't do anything but watch you ping them to death. It's an anti-Timmy combo: instead of putting them out of their misery, it's slow, drawn-out loss.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I can think of is [Lich's Mastery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLich%27s%5d%2b%5bMastery%5d) which is self-inflicted:

> Whenever you lose life, for each 1 life you lost, exile a permanent you control or a card from your hand or graveyard.